Weekly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about Mimblewimble‽
Mimblewimble has been bestowed on us by Tom Elvis Jedusor, and translated by Andrew Poelstra.
To me, it sounds like some marvelous stuff, and we definitely haven't covered it adequately here yet.
Currently, we have only one question about Mimblewimble, let's ask and learn! 
Please use mimblewimble to tag your questions, and consider asking any questions about its scalability, script-affinity, privacy, footprint or whatever else you want to know about it.
This weekly topic challenge runs until 2016-11-17. Happy posting!

This week, two questions were asked about Mimblewimble with a total of one answer (perhaps you can add another?):

How does Mimblewimble's security model compare to Bitcoin's? – nate [+6]
How does MimbleWimble avoid transaction graph leaks? – Nick ODell [+5]

Thanks for posting!
